# Using R to determine author position in journals?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm looking to analyze the order of authors in academic papers, and have a dataset of journals, authors, publication titles, publication dates, etc. that I'm working with. The data comes with each publication title as a row, and the author(s) of the piece listed in a semi-colon-delimited list. For example:

```
authors, pubtitle, title, date
Name 1; Name 2; Name 3, Journal Title, Article Title, 2018
Name 1; Name 2, Journal Title, Article Title, 2019
Name 1; Name 2; Name 3; Name 4; Name 5, Journal Title, Article Title, 2018
```

I've come up with a pretty inefficient way to determine author order, but I'm wondering about suggestions to improve this. Right now, the general workflow looks like this:

```
data_name_listed <- readxl::read_xlsx("data-raw/data.xlsx")
data_name_listed <- data_name_listed %>% 
  rename(author = "Author") %>% 
  rename(title = "Title") %>% 
  rename(pubtitle = "Publication Title") %>% 
  rename(publisher = "Publisher") %>% 
  rename(date = "Date") 

# Select just the author column
data_name_order <- data_name_listed %>% select(author)
data_name_order$author <- str_trim(data_name_order$author)

# Separate lists of names into columns according to the order they appear in the comma-separated list
# This is really inelegant.
data_name_order <- data_name_order %>% 
  separate(col = author, into = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11",
                                  "12","13","14","15", "16","17","18","19","20",
                                  "21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29",
                                  "30","31","32","33","34","35"), sep = ";")

# Gather the data into a tidy df
data_name_order <- data_name_order %>% 
  gather(position, name)
# Clean up special characters in names
data_name_order$name <- gsub("(.*)\\s+[A-Z]\\.?$", "\\1", data_name_order$name)
# Get rid of missing data
data_name_order <- data_name_order %>% drop_na()
# Convert position number to numeric
data_name_order$position <- as.numeric(data_name_order$position)
# Ensure no whitespace
data_name_order$name <- str_trim(data_name_order$name)
# Then merge this data with tidy journal data 
# ... code ...
```

In particular, the `separate()` function is particularly messy, even though it seems to achieve what I hoped it would. I'd love any advice to make this a bit more clean and more reproducible/applicable to other datasets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion without `separate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  select(authors) %>%
  transmute(
    id = row_number(),
    author = strsplit(authors, ";")
  ) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    position = row_number(),
    author = trimws(author)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#       id author position
#    <int> <chr>     <int>
#  1     1 Name 1        1
#  2     1 Name 2        2
#  3     1 Name 3        3
#  4     2 Name 1        1
#  5     2 Name 2        2
#  6     3 Name 1        1
#  7     3 Name 2        2
#  8     3 Name 3        3
#  9     3 Name 4        4
# 10     3 Name 5        5
```

The introduction of `id` into the frame is to work around `tidyr::spread`'s expectation that there are two columns, one to preserve and one to spread. It also (for your case) serves as an ability to re-merge authors back with the original data. If there is a better column that uniquely identifies each row/publication, use that instead. If you have no better fields, then it might be better to add it before you start this process, so "ensure" the original data and this lengthened data have identical ids, perhaps with:

```
x <- mutate(x, id = row_number())
# or with base
x$id <- seq_len(nrow(x))
```

---

Data:

```
x <- read.csv(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
authors, pubtitle, title, date
Name 1; Name 2; Name 3, Journal Title, Article Title, 2018
Name 1; Name 2, Journal Title, Article Title, 2019
Name 1; Name 2; Name 3; Name 4; Name 5, Journal Title, Article Title, 2018")
```

Comment: Fantastic! That seems to do the trick, and much cleaner than my attempt. Thank you!